# Facebook login using native Facebook account (in settings) without web view

Tags: ios, swift3, facebook-login

I created a Facebook login button on iOS with Swift 3, and it works but I'd like to know how to make my button doesn't open a new web view page for asking permissions. I want to show this to user:

[image: What I want]

Does anyone know how to do this?

I searched everywhere but I don't understand how to to it.

Comment: What permission its asking in the image ??

Comment: It's asking for public profile and friends list. I did it but I had the safari web view and I would have the same popup like the picture :/

Comment: Ellaborate "I did it" part of your above comment @Cusmar

Comment: I created a login button and asked for the permissions I need, but instead of having the popup like this image, a safari web view appears with the classic Facebook permission page. Is it more clear?

Comment: What i got from explanation: you want "pop up" to come up as you shown in "image" and not the new web view page for permission (which is appearing). Right?

Comment: Yes that's right!

Comment: @Curmar please correct first line  of your question, it is creating confusion!! :|

Comment: Done! Do you know how to help me?

Comment: I tried to look for your prob, I doubt it possible! :| You don't stop, i will inform you as i get any solution.

Comment: Thanks! I think it is possible, but how? That's the question haha

Answer (score 1):

Below code helps you to provide the access token of the user which is already logged in device. And this access token of user's profile helps you to directly login in Facebook.

In AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,      didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool 
{
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate .sharedInstance() .application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool
{
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

In ViewController:

```
import Social
import Accounts

@IBAction func fbLoginButton(_ sender: Any) 
{

    var facebookAccount: ACAccount?

    let accountStore = ACAccountStore()
    let accountType = accountStore.accountType(
        withAccountTypeIdentifier: ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook)

    let options = [ACFacebookAppIdKey: "YOUR_FB_APP_ID_KEY", ACFacebookPermissionsKey: ["public_profile","email"],ACFacebookAudienceKey:ACFacebookAudienceFriends] as [String : Any]

    let facebookAccountType = accountStore.accountType(withAccountTypeIdentifier: ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook)

    accountStore.requestAccessToAccounts(with: facebookAccountType, options: options) { (success, error) -> Void in
        if success
        {
            let accounts = accountStore.accounts(with: accountType)
            facebookAccount = accounts?.last as? ACAccount
            let accountsArray=accountStore.accounts(with: accountType) as NSArray
            facebookAccount=accountsArray.lastObject as? ACAccount

            print(facebookAccount!)

            var dict:NSDictionary
            dict=NSDictionary()
            dict=facebookAccount!.dictionaryWithValues(forKeys: ["properties"]) as NSDictionary
            let properties:NSDictionary=dict["properties"] as! NSDictionary
            print("facebook Response is ::::",properties)

            print((facebookAccount?.credential.oauthToken)!)

        }
        else
        {
            print("Access denied")
            print((error?.localizedDescription)!)

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you got Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=6 \"(null)\") ? If yes how did you handle it ?

Comment: I discovered that user has to add account in settings. I she/he doesn't this error occur.

Comment: @PiotrBadura soory i dnt get any error like this, if in future i got this one..i'll notify you with answer.

Comment: @PiotrBadura And i also suggest you to take a look on this :

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19853865/ios-facebook-native-login-without-facebook-sdk

Comment: if error is nil if #available(iOS 10.0, *) { UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:"App-Prefs:root=FACEBOO‌​K")!, options: [:]) } else { if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"prefs:root=FACEB‌​OOK")!) { UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string:"prefs:root=FACEBOOK‌​")!) } }

else loginViaFacebook